# How to create blocks matrix?

Tags: matrices

An example: (right matrix)

[image]

I have not found proper answer searching. I need this one for Jordan's normal form

Comment: For this one, a simple  `array{ccc|cc}` and a `\hline` will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}ccc|cc@{}}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_{11} & b_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_{21} & b_{22} \\\hline
    c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} & d_{11} & d_{12} \\
    c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & d_{21} & d_{22} \\
    c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & d_{31} & d_{32} 
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha, I just thought (from the start), that something like special-matrix env. exists

Comment: @M.Mass There are special matrix environments, like `matrix` and `pmatrix`, defined in `amsmath` but they do not support the lines. See e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics (about halfway down the page)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to highlight blocks in a `matrix` environment easily with `pstricks` without increasing the column widths: adding `pnode`s (empty nodes) at the relevant places and defining `\psframe`s from pairs of nodes.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}%

\begin{document}

\[ A = \begin{pmatrix}
   M_{11} & M_{12}\\\
M_{21} & M_{22}
 \end{pmatrix}
  =
 \begin{pspicture}
 $ \begin{pmatrix}
    \pnode[-0.3ex, 1.5ex]{A}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & b_{11} & b_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & b_{21} & b_{22} \\
    c_{11} & c_{12} &
    c_{13} \pnode[1.4ex, -0.8ex]{C} & d_{11} & d_{12} \\
    c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} & d_{21} & d_{22} \\
    c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33} & d_{31} & d_{32}\pnode[0.2ex, -0.6ex]{D}\,
  \end{pmatrix} $
\psset{linecolor = IndianRed}
\psframe(A)(C)
\psset{dimen = inner}\psframe(C)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]